# Jboss AS 7.1.1 Access/Query Embedded H2 Database

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, jboss7.x, h2

I'm trying to access my embedded h2 server and query. I can access, but the tables I have created don't appear on the Jboss H2 tool.

Here is my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/xxxDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- For auto create tables on startup -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**xxx-ds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">

    <!--  start H2 DATABASE -->
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xxxDS"
        pool-name="xxx" enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:xxx;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

accessing the H2 embedded database by the Jboss tool (see the test successful on the image): 
java -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.3.161.jar
[image: the screenshot]

I can connect, but I cannot see the tables I've created in the application. I only see the h2 system tables.
[image: I cannot see my tables created]

How can I see the tables my application is persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using in-memory database so accessing from different JVM and class loader environment won't work.

As you are using Jboss 7 you can use the **h2console** quickstart to view the database content. [Here is the project](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.1.1.Final/h2-console), it builds a *war* that you just have to deploy in `<jboss_home>/(domain|standalone)/deployments`.

Also take note that with the option *create-drop* for *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto* will drop any database object when the applications is undelployed.

If you have chance to change the h2 database configuration, you could set its **server mode**. See [this short tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/h2-database-tutorial) to know how to do it fast :)